# heroku command not working error Installing core plugins

Tags: heroku

I'm keep getting this error. I have installed heroku toolkit successfully

> C:\Users\hp-u>heroku login
>   Would you like to submit Heroku CLI usage information to better improve the CLI user experience?
>   [y/N] Y
>   heroku-cli: Installing core plugins...Error reading plugin heroku-apps. 
>   Reinstalling... Error reading plugin heroku-apps. Reinstalling ... Error reading plugin heroku-apps. Reinstalling

Answer (score 0):

I removed the s from https:// in the value HTTPS_PROXY variable and it worked.

so:

```
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://myproxy.com:8080"
//instead of
export HTTPS_PROXY="https://myproxy.com:8080"
```

i.e. somehow the internal college proxy itself might not be able to perform SSL communication